# MySQL. Join tables from different servers

Tags: php, mysql, federated

How to make JOIN between two tables from two different databases on two different servers without using FEDERATED tables? Is there any another architectural solutions for it in web-application powered by PHP?

Comment: I only recognize 4 words here and a few exclamation points and the tags. In English please.

Comment: or http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ok, how to make JOIN between two tables from two different databases on two different servers without using FEDERATED tables? Is there any another architectural solutions for it in web-application powered by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

How to join tables from different servers without using *the technology explicitly designed for the purpose* (which, aside from a few quirks relating to optimization of views, works very well)? You'll have to write the code yourself.